# How to download a whole thread as pdf/html

Tags: windows-10, macos, pdf, screenshot

I tried everything accessible to a non-coder user to download a thread from [here](https://www.forexfactory.com/forums) but no success overall.

My aim is to download an html version of a thread **with the ability of navigating trough pages**, if that's not possible I would be ok even with a pdf. I can not manually do that because some thread I want to download have 1k+ pages, [example](https://www.forexfactory.com/thread/57639-technical-analysis-fallacy).
If downloading an html would require too much effort i'm ok even with pdf.

Hope some of you could help. Thank's.

Ps: being a noob I may used wrong settings with the most famous app called HTTracks, I got mirror errors and checked how to fix on internet but no success.

Pps: I tried using wget but with no success as I get error: "503 Service Temporarily Unavailable". I tried even the curl command on mac but the result is an html file that only display the loading screen of ddos protection.

Edit: httrack made it to download but it seems there's an "automatic redirect", so when I open the file for some seconds I see the thread, but after even if I'm online the site redirect me to the main page.

Comment: Does this attempt go counter to the Terms of Use of that forum?

Comment: "Users are not permitted to interfere with Services or try to access them using a method other than the interface and the instructions that FEI provides". From [Forex Factory Notices](https://www.forexfactory.com/notices#terms_of_service)

Comment: @music2myear: There is also a copyright notice, but for personal use this isn't forbidden.

Comment: @DavidPostill: If he uses the HTML to capture all the pages, he's doing it via the official interface.

Comment: @Edoardo: Which browser are you using? You do understand that capturing these 3173 pages, you will end up with 3173 files?

Comment: @harrymc Yes I would like have an offline copy of the thread given in the example. Plus I don't think it's against some term of use, it's just a forum run by users, no copyrighted content. I'm on google chrome.

Comment: Nevertheless, there is a copyright notice that you must honor - you may use it as a personal backup only. Which browser are you using as your main browser? Will Chrome do?

Comment: I intended to use it as a personal backup from the beginning. I'm using chrome as already said. Is there a solution to my problem or not?

Comment: There is always a way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The example is particularly easy to do because the URL to access each
page is straight-forward:
`https://www.forexfactory.com/thread/57639-technical-analysis-fallacy?page=NUMBER`.

You may use the free [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/).

The following example script will make the hotkey
<kbd>F12</kbd>
position to all the pages and print each one:

```
baseURL=https://www.forexfactory.com/thread/57639-technical-analysis-fallacy?page=
baseFilename=C:\Temp\technical-analysis-fallacy-page-

F12::
Loop,3173
{
    index=%A_Index%                         ; keep loop index
    pageURL = %baseURL%%index%              ; URL of current page
    fileName = %baseFilename%%index%.pdf    ; file name for current page
    WinActivate, ahk_exe chrome.exe         ; ensure chrome is active
    Sleep, 1000
    SendInput, !d                           ; alt-d positions to address filed
    Sleep, 200
    SendInput, ^a                           ; ctrl-a selects all of it
    Sleep, 200
    SendInput, {Del}                        ; delete current address field content
    Sleep, 200
    SendInput, %pageURL%{Enter}             ; enter page url and execute
    Sleep, 2000
    SendInput, ^p                           ; enter print menu      
    Sleep, 2000
    SendInput, {Enter}                      ; execute the Save button
    Sleep, 2000
    SendInput, %fileName%{Enter}            ; set the file name snd enter to execute
}
```

Usage notes:

- You must first ensure that "Save as PDF" is the default printer
  for Chrome. Printing once to it will set it as default.
- Chrome must be launched before executing
- You may start with a smaller number than 3173, perhaps 2 or 3,
  until you are sure that it works correctly
- Turn off your printer, just in case.

After installing AutoHotKey, put the above text in a `.ahk` file and
double-click it to test. You may stop the script by right-click on
the green H icon in the traybar and choosing Exit.

Useful AutoHotkey documentation:

- [List of Keys](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/KeyList.htm)
- [Hotkeys](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm)

Comment: Thenk's I managed to make it work, really apreciate your help. Anyway is there a way to make the content with an interface more similar to the site? Some posts get splitted and so on.

Comment: That's Chrome's "Save as PDF" that's doing that. You could try perhaps another PDF printer.

Comment: Ok thank's, what could I use?

Comment: There's Microsoft Print to PDF that's built-in, or many other PDF viewers come also with printers.

Comment: Ok thank's very much for your help. Do you know some of them which may suit better my needs? I've tried googling but no success. 
Also, is there a way to save the whole thread as html? As you saw from the original question I tried the most common ways but no success.

Comment: You can save it as 3173 HTML files, by replacing the ` SendInput, ^p` with ` SendInput, ^s` for saving the page. You should then remove the following `SendInput, {Enter}` and modify the `fileName =` assignment.

Comment: Eh, that's the problem. Try to do it by yourself, press ctrl+s then close internet connection and open the file. You'll see the main page for 1 sec and then you'll be automatically redirected to the main page.

Comment: That's a problem with the website. I can't help more than that. You might want to disable JavaScript for the copy using a browser extension such as NoScript or equivalent.

Comment: That's don't make any difference. Thank's anyway

Comment: Is this your work?

Comment: It's originally mine.

Comment: I've done it. Please if you come up with a solution for saving the pages in html I would aprecaite it.